# Почему nginx может отдавать 400?

Tags: nginx, настройка

Десктоп приложение отправляет файлы HTTP POST запросом.
На апач всё приходит отлично, а вот nginx не пропускает и отдает 400.
Что ему может не нравиться?
При чем, отправляю такой же запрос через curl - ошибки нет...
Привожу заголовки:
Рабочие заголовки (от запроса, который обрабатывается нормально, отправляю курлом):

```
host: 123.45.56
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Название приложения
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=5873ed5c762ec
content-length: 432929
```

Заголовки от приложения, запрос с которыми не проходит:

```
host: 123.45.56
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Название приложения
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
accept-language: en-us,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate
accept-charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
keep-alive: 300
connection: keep-alive
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------587132587349317
content-length: 300000
```

Изменить заголовки, отправляемые приложением - нет возможности...

Конфиги nginx:
nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    client_header_buffer_size 8k;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

default.conf

```
server {
    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name "";
    root        /home/user/www/web/domain.ru;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log  /home/user/www/log/access.log;
    error_log   /home/user/www/log/error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f user@domain.ru";
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=/home/user/www/:.";
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "upload_tmp_dir=/home/user/www/tmp";
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "session.save_path=/home/user/www/tmp";
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "display_errors=On";
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

P.S. Методом тыка определил, что проблема в этом заголовке:
    content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------587132587349317
Видимо из-за этих тире. Проверял курлом с этим заголовком - PHP запрос не получает, но nginx отдает 200 нормально.
Удаляю этот заголовок - запрос проходит...

Comment: Да не, такой заголовок с такими дефисами это норма, вообще на первый взгляд всё вроде в порядке, странно

Comment: Я вот так же думаю, что там всё нормально с заголовками. но, всё таки, запрос не проходит...